# Strange behavior of regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

In one of my projects, the application has to check that a link to a given URL exists in a given page. Today a user reported an error. This was the link that the application was not detecting:

```
  <a\nhref="http://hello.com"...
```

I tried to test why it was not working, and here is where the strange behavior appeared. This Regexp matches the link:

```
/\<a.*\nhref=\"http:\/\/hello.com/
```

But this does not:

```
/\<a.*href=\"http:\/\/hello.com/
```

I guess it has some relation with the Ruby version I'm using (1.9.3), as Rubular matches the last regexp.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse an HTML document.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván: This is one occasion where regex is actually (possibly) OK. Ill-advised, but [Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) won't consume you just for using regex to check if a link exists in a document.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Unless, you know, it's in an HTML comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why It Is Broken

In Ruby (as with most regex implementations) the `.` matches any character *except a newline* unless you turn on the "multiline" mode:

```
irb(main):003:0> "foo\nbar"[/.+/]
#=> "foo"

irb(main):004:0> "foo\nbar"[/.+/m]
#=> "foo\nbar"
```

As the [official Ruby 1.9 regex documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/re.rdoc) states:

> The following metacharacters also behave like character classes:
>   `/./` - Any character except a newline.
>   `/./m` - Any character (the m modifier enables multiline mode)

When your code explicitly consumed the `\n` all worked well, but when you switched it to just `.*` it could not match the `\n` and thus could not continue on to match `href`.

### Fixing it Better

Instead of using regex to ~parse and consume HTML, it's better to use [a real HTML parser](http://nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri' # gem install nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri.HTML( my_html_string )

# Find it using XPath...
first_hello_link = doc.at('//a[starts-with(@href,"http://hello.com")]')

# ...or using CSS
first_hello_link = doc.at('a[href^="http://hello.com"]')
```

With this your code can robustly handle HTML with:

- spaces before or after the equals sign
- additional attributes appearing before href
- quoting with either `"` or `'`
- mixed capitalization
- things that look like links but aren't (e.g. in a comment or script block)

Comment: Yes, I probably should use Nokogiri. But it's a classic: you start with an extremely simple parser and it starts to grow more and more until Nokogiri starts to be almost mandatory.

Comment: @Christian - It won't take too many of these experiences before you just pull out Nokogiri any time you have xml or html in your hands, no matter how simple the parsing seems.  It _always_ grows to be too complex for a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Regexps in ruby don't match newline characters by default, you must add the `m` modifier:

```
/pat/m - Treat a newline as a character matched by .
```

Take a look at the options section:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Comment: It's only the dot metacharacter (`.`) that doesn't match newlines by default.  If there were no dots in the regex, you wouldn't need the `m` flag.